# Принято ли создавать в локальной базе данных aspnetdb.mdf - свои таблицы, связи? Или в этой БД находятся только профили?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Или в этой БД находятся только профили, пароли и роли? Можно ли таблицу Users (Которая автоматически создается с membership api) дополнить столбцы: (профессия, возраст, хобби) связать с какой нибудь своей таблицей? И вообще, принято ли так делать?

Или правильнее будет не изменять базу данных aspnetdb.mdf и создать вторую БД, полностью такую же, но дополненную своими столбцами/таблицами/связями?

Comment: Можно добавлять столбцы, обычно так и делают. Не надо второй базы. Мне например не нравится string в поле id пользователя -- я понимаю, зачем так сделала Майкрософт, но меняю на int. Код не храм, а мастерская. Нечего его под музейное стекло помещать, не бойтесь править если надо.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте от более общих вопросов к частным.

У вас есть задание написать некоторый веб-сайт по определённым требованиям. Вы берёте требования и пишите тот код, который нужен для этого конкретного сайта (а тот который не нужен -- не пишете, логично?)

Как правило, в программировании уже есть наработки, которые позволяют сделать типовые задачи, не создавая собственный "велосипед". Многие наработки -- это уже готовые библиотеки, фреймворки и т.п.

ASP.Net Identity -- как раз такой удобный фундамент, который позволяет начать писать собственный код, по-минимуму отвлекаясь на т.н. "бойлерплейт": у вас уже есть достаточно много готового кода, который вероятнее всего подойдёт именно вам. Но не надо думать, что вы должны молиться на этот код или что вам запрещено его менять: возможно, что у вас немного нетиповые требования и вам нужно немного переделать реализацию так, чтобы она подходила именно вам.
Не бойтесь заглянуть в код identity, он несложный и не бойтесь его менять -- в принципе, это лишь фундамент и набор некоторых базовых кубиков для вашей стройки.

Потребности выносить в отдельную базу нет никакой необходимости, более того -- это будет неудобно в плане миграций Enity Framework и манипуляции с DbContext. Я как-то пробовал смотреть в эту сторону -- сложно, на практике неудобно. Держите таблицы проекта в одной базе.

В плане отдельной таблицы под поля профессии, пола/возраста или хранения в штатной таблице пользователей. Видел и первый вариант и второй вариант. Я бы обращал внимание на логическую структуру. Допустим, если вы хотите выделить UserSettings в отдельную таблицу -- ну так и сделайте отдельную таблицу со связью один-к-одному, но теория реляционных баз данных говорит, что в этом случае фактически речь идёт об одной таблице и можно их слить в одну. Если вы видите потребность выделить явно таблицу UserProfile -- выделяйте, тут нужно от проекта идти.

В моём опыте я чаще не заморачивался с отдельными таблицами для полей пользователя, а добавлял в существующие. Работает прекрасно.

В интернете есть примеры того, как поменять тип поля ID для таблицы пользователей со string (у MS это планировалось под GUID пользователя) на int. Поле email можно сделать необязательным или можно добавить поля Login, DisplayName (по умолчанию вы указываете для входа email). Можно добавлять собственные поля (возраст, профессия и т.п.) С этим нет проблем. Asp.Net Identity -- достаточно гибкий фреймворк, можно под себя допилить как надо.